# Width of <selects> in Safari 5.0.5 for Windows

Tags: css, webforms, safari

I'm developing a web form, and works well in Firefox 4 and 3.6, Chromium 11, Opera 11.10, and IE 8, but in Safari 5.0.5 for Windows, all `<select>`s have more width, thus breaking the layout. This is a screenshot comparing the reult with Firefox 3.6:

[image]

The weird thing is that in Safari 5.0.5 for Mac it is displayed as expected. What could be happening? It seems that the arrow is using space beyond its box. Here is the CSS:

```
select{
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;
    display:block;
    height:19px;
    margin:0;
    padding:1px;
    background:#eee;
    border:1px solid #a7a7a7;
    width:128px;
}
```

By the way, Firebug Lite for Safari reports the same computed width that in other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. It hides the dropdown-arrow on the right of the select element. So, you can add your own arrow with `#select-arrow { pointer-events:none; }` and have more control over the select element. See comment: "It seems that the arrow is using space beyond its box." - just add your own.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your select boxes are the ones that are causing the problem.

Some browsers will force the select box width to be at least as wide as the widest option in the given select. See if this is the problem you are having by trimming down the number of characters in your options.

Comment: some `<select>`s are empty, but the problem remains :(

Comment: Interesting. I just tested a similarly styled <select> in safari for mac (v 5.0.5) and it matches firefox perfectly. Maybe I could help troubleshoot with some more markup...but this could be a PC/Safari-specific issue.